# Modern CV cover letter template not hyphenating words at the end of the line

Tags: templates, hyphenation

I am using the Modern CV Cover letter [template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cover-letters/moderncv-classic) but the hyphenation at the end of the line is not working. Here you have an [example](https://surfdrive.surf.nl/files/index.php/s/evPRevAZYRUv7fS) of the cover letter with text in English and you can see how the hyphenation does not work and a lot of space is wasted in the document. The problem persists even when adding `\usepackage[english]{babel}` in the preamble.

I have tried the solutions proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102283/hyphenation-not-working-in-cover-letter-template) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76015/justify-text-in-moderncv-cover-letter), but they do not seem to work.

Comment: Don't link to some external resources - such links dies and will make your question invalid. Add a short complete example of your code in your question.

Comment: I created a zip file and linked it in the question, I hope this is OK now

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: No the zip file is at an external site. Your question will be archived here forever and will not make sense if the link breaks and many people would not open a link to an unknown site like that. Make a small example document and add it as text in a code block in the question.

Comment: However that said, the image that you show here https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cover-letters/moderncv-classic  clearly shows that the letter is set ragged right so hyphenation is not usually required.

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin the solutions in the proposed duplicate seem not to hyphenate, so I guess that is not what the OP wanted?

Comment: @Marijn they allow hyphenation, even if the mock latin example doesn't need it.

Comment: Also, never trust a template.  Some of them are truly awful.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: 1) I cannot copy-paste in the body of the question a MWE, I need to paste like 6 files and I get the message "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 36256." after 3 of the 6 files. How can I upload my MWE? And yes I need all the files otherwise it does not compile 2) Why did you say that hyphenation is not required? My issue is that I would like to hyphenate the words and I don't know how to do it.

@ Marijn: you are right, the proposed solution does not hyphenate my English letter

Comment: The M in MWE stands for _minimal_ you should not post your entire CV, start with a copy of your CV delete everything except one paragraph that is not hyphenating as you expect, then delete any definitions and packages that are not required for the example, check the remaining document demonstrates that issue. It is unlikely that you need to post ore than a dozen lines or so. It is _much_ easier for you to make an example, starting from the document you have, than it is for anyone trying to help to guess an example given no information.

Comment: Why was the question closed and flagged as duplicate? The proposed solution does not solve my issue and I still cannot hyphenate my letter

Comment: fo (2) when I said hyphenation is not required I meant because the examples that you linked to are using ragged right setting so tex doesn't hyphenate words, it only needs to hyphenate if justifying the right margin.

Comment: the proposed solutions in the linked document re-enable justified paragraphs so will re-enable hyphenation. Unless you have code that you have not shown that is disabling it explicitly, but it is impossible to guess what code you may have.